# Trying to port this C# math to PHP: int mask = 1 << (i - 1);

Tags: c#, php, .net, math

I'm trying to port this C# math (I presume?) to PHP: `int mask = 1 << (i - 1);`
Here is the full C# code of the function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts tile XY coordinates into a QuadKey at a specified level of detail.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tileX">Tile X coordinate.</param>
/// <param name="tileY">Tile Y coordinate.</param>
/// <param name="levelOfDetail">Level of detail, from 1 (lowest detail)
/// to 23 (highest detail).</param>
/// <returns>A string containing the QuadKey.</returns>
public static string TileXYToQuadKey(int tileX, int tileY, int levelOfDetail)
{
    StringBuilder quadKey = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = levelOfDetail; i > 0; i--)
    {
        char digit = '0';
        int mask = 1 << (i - 1);
        if ((tileX & mask) != 0)
        {
            digit++;
        }
        if ((tileY & mask) != 0)
        {
            digit++;
            digit++;
        }
        quadKey.Append(digit);
    }
    return quadKey.ToString();
}
```

And here is the PHP code I've ended up with:

```
<?php
/*
* PHP class for converting Mercator X, Y and Z
* coordinates to Bing Maps Quad tree key
* Ported from C# code from MSDN
* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx
*
* Usage:
* mercatorQuadkey(z, x, y)
* Example:
* mercatorQuadkey(15, 5240, 12661)
*/
function mercatorQuadkey($z, $x, $y){
    for ($i = $levelOfDetail; $i > 0; $i--)
    {
        $digit = '0';
        $mask = 1 << ($i - 1);
        if ($tileX !== 0 && $mask !== 0)
        {
            $digit++;
        }
        if ($tileY !== 0 && $mask !== 0)
        {
            $digit++;
            $digit++;
        }
        $quadkey = $quadkey.$digit;
    }
    return $quadkey;
}
?>
```

Can anyone help?
I need this because I am trying to use Bing Maps in Leaflet but all of the plugins I've found have no usage example.
I know nothing about C#, by the way.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what problem you are having with your PHP code.  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I am getting a blank result when I run `echo mercatorQuadkey(15, 5240, 12661);`.

Comment: Where is levelOfDetail assigned a value in your function?

Comment: `digit = '0'`? Try without quotes. Quotation signs are used for Strings, not for Integers in PHP.

Comment: `$levelOfDetail` should be `$y` in Your PHP code...

Comment: This should work in my opinion

Comment: @shadyyx I think it should be $z now I think of that :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems. First, it appears you renamed the variables in your PHP function, without renaming the references in the code.  Put the original variable names back:

```
function mercatorQuadkey($tileX, $tileY, $levelOfDetail){
```

Second, the logic for `if ((tileX & mask) != 0)` is directly convertible to PHP.  This is a binary AND (`&`), not a logical AND (`&&`), which are completely different things:

```
    if (($tileX & $mask) !== 0)
    {
        $digit++;
    }
    if (($tileY & $mask) !== 0)
    {
        $digit++;
        $digit++;
    }
```

With these changes, both codes return the same result:

- C#: http://ideone.com/hHXEEj
- PHP: http://ideone.com/oOydCg

Comment: OK, any idea how I'd use this with Bing Maps?

Comment: If this answers your question, mark it so.  If you have a different question than what you asked, then **start a new question** *after you've done thorough research*, and you've run into a another problem.

Comment: [link](http://tinyurl.com/by6dlt2) (TinyURL since it was too long for SO by 76128 chars or something) seems to be a blank image. Any idea how I can use it with Bing Maps? (Edit: I'm asking a new question now)

Comment: @JoshyK. - By "new question", he means make a separate post.  That way, posts are useful to future readers because they each focus on one specific issue.

Comment: @mbeckish I have done that.